What would prevent java garbage collection from cleaning heap?
Two k8s pods running the same image (using Adoptium 17 JRE).
Around 9pm, they start getting requests and objects are getting created.
On the blue pod, we can see the garbage collection working correctly.
But on the red pod, the eden space spikes (total mem usage around 90%) and never comes down.
Pods have since been restarted, so no further evidence available, but I'm curious to get some opinions on what could cause the behavior of the red pod shown in the graph.  Why would cause the memory utilization to stay high like this?  The pod was still alive and processing requests, just complaining frequently about being unable to create new pthreads due to lack of resources.


Interesting. Are you sure you don't have threads locking up due to some I/O timeout or similar? Because creating a pthread in itself should not be that mem intensive, right? What I'm saying is that the memory issue may be the effect rather than the cause.

What do the lines represent? The blue seem to show garbage collection activity in the typical pattern. What is the red line? What is the application doing? How many threads and what were they doing? You don't have a heap dump, not even a thread dump. Not even the actual error messages about not enough threads. There is no useful information to make a guess.

Each line represents the eden memory usage for one pod.  The red and blue lines are the same metric for 2 pods of the same service.  The blue one is performing garbage collection correctly, the red one has allocated all memory and not releasing it.

The red line is basically impossible to get from heap usage, a JVM that fills up, can't free heap but doesn't crash would be a 1 in a million. Even just recording the heap usage uses heap and would crash or create a saw tooth pattern. How exactly do you record these values?

@zapi New Relic infra agent

If the red line denotes the amount of used heap space in a JVM, then that JVM is inactive; i.e. it is not processing requests.  A JVM that is active will be generating garbage and the JVM should periodically run the GC ... leading to the classic saw-tooth pattern.  Conversely, if garbage is being generated and not being collected, then line will not be horizontal.
So:

Check that the red line actually represents the used (Eden) heap space and not the total heap space.  The fact that it is a flat line is inexplicable if it is the used heap space on an active JVM.

Check that the "red" JVM has not locked up.

Check that the (K8s?) load balancer is directing requests to both pods.

Check that the values being reported are current not a stale value from the last successful report; i.e. from the "red" JVM.



I removed the chart legend before posting image.  Each line represents the Eden memory usage for one pod.

Then you need to investigate the other things I suggested.
